# How to skip archives internals in Windows search (by string in a filename)?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-search

Using (Microsoft) Windows Search (Chtrl+F), I am trying to find a file by a string in filename.
Oops, it seems never-ending process because it is perusing all archives (zip, et al) internals.
While I need only the names search (of file names in a file system without searching files inside archives)

How can I search only by file names without search looking inside archives?

Answer (score 1):

If you use this method, Windows XP searches all file types for the text that 
you specify. This can affect the performance of the search functionality. To 
do this:

```
1. Click Start, and then click Search (or point to Search, and then 
click For Files or Folders). 
2. Click Change preferences, and then click With Indexing Service (for 
faster local searches). 
3. Click Change Indexing Service Settings (Advanced). Note that you do 
not have to turn on the Index service. 
4. On the toolbar, click Show/Hide Console Tree. 
5. In the left pane, right-click Indexing Service on Local Machine, 
and then click Properties. 
6. On the Generation tab, click to select the Index files with unknown 
extensions check box, and then click OK. 
7. Close the Indexing Service console.
```

Comment: Hi, mahinos, I do not have "Change Indexing Service Settings (Advanced)" inside options on step 3. I have "Change files and folders behavior" with just 2 dead-end radio-buttons (Standard... and Advanced) after choosing which I am returned to previous choices. Advanced is chosen but I have no clue how to continue and follow step 4